# How to apply an insertion sort for a title and a number in JavaScript

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I am currently trying to write a program that will allow me to use insertion sorting to find the title and to find the year in which the movie was released. Currently whenever I compile and run the program, I end up with a random String that looks like this "[LMovie2;@15f45c9" however, it is different every single time. If someone could help me get an idea of where I am going wrong,(possibly in my array) that would be awesome. I would also like feedback on how to ask questions since this is my first post. Thank you for your time and consideration.

```
public class Movie2
{
private String title;
private int year;
private String studio;

public Movie2(String t, int y, String s)
{
    title = t;
    studio = s;
    year = y;
}
public String toString()
{
    String movies;
    movies = title + " \t" + year + "\t" + studio;

    return movies;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String t)
{
    title = t;
}
public String getStudio()
{
    return studio;
}
public void setStudio(String s)
{
    studio = s;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int y)
{
    year = y;
}

}

public class testMovies2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Movie2[] movies = new Movie2[10];

   movies[0] = new Movie2("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia   Tristar");
   movies[1] = new Movie2("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");
   movies[2] = new Movie2("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
   movies[3] = new Movie2("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
   movies[4] = new Movie2("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");
   movies[5] = new Movie2("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
   movies[6] = new Movie2("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");
   movies[7] = new Movie2("Lilo & Stitch", 2002, "Disney");
   movies[8] = new Movie2("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
   movies[9] = new Movie2("Monsters Inc.", 2001, "Pixar");

   System.out.println(movies);
}
public static void insertionSort(Movie2[] a)
{
 int[] source = { 12, 14, 15, 11, 13 };
 int[] dest = new int[ source.length ];

 for ( int i = 0 ; i < source.length ; i++ )
 {
int next = source[ i ];
int insertindex = 0;
int k = i;
while ( k > 0 && insertindex == 0 )
{
if ( next > dest[ k - 1 ] )
{
  insertindex = k;
}
else
{
  dest[ k ] = dest[ k - 1 ];
}
k--;
}

dest[ insertindex ] = next;
}
}


}
```

Comment: Why is there Javascript in your title when the question is about Java? The 2 languages are nothing alike.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your movies

Change this

```
System.out.println(movies);
```

to

```
for(Movie2 m : movies)
System.out.println(m.toString());
```